# CrunchBase-like system

Tags: database, content-management-system, platform

What's the best platform for creating a CrunchBase like system? (has to be open source). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, and there is never "one" answer to a question "which is the best for ..." ; still :

You are looking for a piece of software that allows, at least from what I can see on the site :

- users to register / login
- edition of content
- keeping of revisions history
- tagging / categorization of pages
- rss (both aggregating rss and generating rss)
- comments on articles
- couple of lists like "recently added", "recently modified"
- some kind of search

That's the kind of stuff almost any CMS will do out of the box, I suppose...

If you are looking for something OpenSource, the next question is "which language / technology / platform"...

If you are going for somemthing Apache+PHP+MySQL based, [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) is quite good piece of software, and you can do lots of things with not much coding, provided you use the right modules... and, as far as I can tell, it does what I listed before.

Of course, knowing a bit more about what you need / want might help us help you more ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Druapl would be perfect for this, alas: I'm looking for cheaper development.

Would you recommended ELGG for such a project? The main idea is indexing People/Comapnies/Organizations and display their connections and individual data.

Comment: I don't know about ELGG, sorry ; never used it at all. Still, whichever tool you choose, you'll probably have to expect spending/investing some time in development (if it's not coding for the backend, you'll still have to spend some time customizing the presentation of the site, I suppose) : you don't create a website out of thin air ;-)

Comment: I used to use ELGG but it came to be very difficult to manage for spamming posts, we need more attention to manage things on ELGG since I had not much time to do. I left ELGG for awhile now. I'm also interesting on such kind of CrunchBase